# Visual Studio 2012 Remote Kernel Debugging a Virtual Machine

Tags: visual-studio-2012, kernel, virtual-machine, remote-debugging, device-driver

I'm having some troubles setting up a debug environment with the following configuration:

```
Host computer - Physical, Windows 7 x64

Target computer - Virtual (Vmware), Windows 7 x64 (Running on Host computer)
```

I want to be able to develop a kernel mode driver, deploy and debug it in my VM.

Visual Studio is giving me a hard time, and provisioning the VM fails to work.

How can I successfully deploy and debug a driver in a VM ?

Comment: After many days I finally found a solution, I published a step by step article in CodeProject explaining what needs to be done: http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ArticleVersion.aspx?waid=61935&aid=545835

Comment: I followed the steps you outlined on StackOverflow and CodeProject, and still couldn't get the debugger to connect. I tried with VMWare and VirtualBox separately. Then, I found a simple sentence buried in the MSDN article "[Configuring a Computer for Driver Deployment, Testing, and Debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh698272%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)," which states: Provisioning is not supported for virtual machines. If you were able to connect the debugger to a VM, I encourage you to share the details with the rest of the development community.

Comment: Despite the statement in MSDN, I managed to provision a Virtual Machine, that is why I felt it was absolutely important to share this knowledge with the community !
It took me a lot of time to understand how, and a lot of studying how kernel debugging was done in the "old" days (using WinDBG) but I have succeeded and this article (And the one in Code Project) explains step by step how this is done.

Please explain what steps have you succeeded and where are you stuck, I will be glad to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by myself.
I wrote an article about the solution [here](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ArticleVersion.aspx?waid=175295&aid=545835).

Answer (score 0):

To connect to a VMware target on the same machine, I simply used a serial cable to connect to each "half". My serial cables have USB at each end. So I just connect the ends to separate USB ports on my computer.

Comment: If you gave some details, then you might get upvotes for this answer.